# Статические массивы c++

Tags: c++

```
const string waitArray[9] {
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
}
```

ошибка expected a declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Знак `=` стоит добавить:

```
const string waitArray[9] = {
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
};
```